# Grails error installing plugin rest-client-builder 1.0.2, bad module descriptor

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

Using Grails 2.0.4, I'm trying to install `rest-client-builder:1.0.2` using this...

```
grails install-plugin rest-client-builder
```

...but Grails returns the error below; I've tried cleaning, refreshing dependencies, etc., keep getting the same error...

```
:: #rest-client-builder;1.0.2: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://plugins.grails.org/grails-rest-client-builder/tags/RELEASE_1_0_2/rest-client-builder-1.0.2.pom': bad organisation: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins';
```

Also tried linking the plugin as a dependency from `BuildConfig.groovy`, but I get a similar error...

```
compile (":rest-client-builder:1.0.2"){ export = false}

grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://plugins.grails.org/grails-rest-client-builder/tags/RELEASE_1_0_2/rest-client-builder-1.0.2.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you put it in the `dependencies` section but it should be in the `plugins` section:

```
plugins {
   compile(':rest-client-builder:1.0.2') {
      export = false
   }
}
```

You should remove the plugins that are still in `application.properties` that the `install-plugin` script adds and only have them in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue...ty, Burt.